# Error while running appium code

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I am new to appium. I am getting below error when i Run appium code in eclipse:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:   Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{app=D:\Workspace\Mobile\Apps\ATT\AT.apk, appPackage=com.atp.android, appActivity=Splash, appium-version=1.6.4, platformVersion=6.0, platformName=Android, deviceName=Test}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
```

Code:

```
   private static AndroidDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        AppiumDriver driver;
        File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "/Apps/AST/");
        File app = new File(appDir, "AT.apk");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.6.4");
        //capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Test");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.atp.android");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "Splash");

        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.quit();
```

Selenium version is 3.4
Please help to resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: What does the appium server log say?

Comment: I see an error in aapium logs like "[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Command 'java' not found. Is it installed?"

Comment: Is Java installed on the system the Appium server runs on and does it have it available in Path. You can check it by running a terminal with the command java -version

Comment: I ran that command, 1.8 version of Java is installed in the system.

Comment: How is your JAVA_HOME system variable configured?

Comment: JAVA_HOME is set to 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79'

Comment: It could be that your Java SDK is broken, but I can't say for sure. You can try to reinstall java by removing it in control panel and then install it from a fresh download. Also check if there isn't a 32 bit version of java hiding somewhere when you are using 64 bit

Comment: nope...not working, getting same error.

Comment: @john did you start appium server manually, before you run the java code?

Comment: capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "Splash"); comment out this or provide full name of your activity with package. i.e. com.abc.app.Splash

Answer (score 0):

You can try to comment the following two lines and see how does it work:

```
   capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.atp.android");
   capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "Splash");
```

since when you run test on a complicate app, it's hard to make sure the content of apppackage and app are set right. Appium will help you to find the correct content automatically instead.